# Keytool utility not available

Tags: linux, java, oracle-linux, jdk, oracle-vm-server

I know that in order to use keytool, JDK must be installed -- which it is in my server -- but the keytool utility is not available.

```
[root@Linux ~]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
[root@Linux ~]$ 
[root@Linux ~]$ which keytool 
/usr/bin/which: no keytool in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/opc/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin) 
[root@Linux ~]$ [root@Linux ~]$ locate keytool 
/etc/alternatives/keytool
/etc/alternatives/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el6_10.x86_64/jre/bin/keytool
/usr/share/man/man1/keytool-java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el6_10.x86_64.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you apparently have that java directory in your PATH, or symlinks from your PATH into that directory. What is the output from `type java`?

Comment: See the formatting change I applied to make it easier -- use the `{}` button to indent code or output, instead of having to use HTML.

Comment: [root@Linux ~]$type java 
Output:
java is hashed (/usr/bin/java)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you're just missing some symlinks; on my system, there's:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el6_10.x86_64/jre/bin/keytool /etc/alternatives/keytool
```

and

```
ln -s /etc/alternatives/keytool /usr/bin/keytool
```

where the symlinks are expected to be managed by the package manager.

Comment: It is really safe/wise to temper with the symlinks otherwise maintained by `alternatives`?

Comment: certainly, as I said -- the symlinks are expected to be managed by the package manager; they appeared to be missing for the OP, so I suggested recreating them.